# Which is faster: Math.abs(value) or value * -1 ?

Tags: javascript, performance

Pretty straightforward, but I just want to know which is faster.

I think simply multiplying a number by `-1` is much faster than calling a predefined method, provided that you are sure that value is negative.

But if that's the case then what is the `abs()` function for? Is it simply for making sure that the value returned would always be positive regardless of value's sign?

Comment: It may, in fact, be faster to use -x rather than x * -1.

Comment: Quick answer for the people of the future: [neither, really.](http://jsperf.com/abs-vs-n1)

Comment: ..unless you use a custom function: http://jsperf.com/math-abs-vs-custom-abs-function where `Math.abs()` wins massively over anything else.

Comment: according to this test: http://jsben.ch/#/ZJRAv ..there should be almost no difference.

Comment: High value optimizations

Answer (score 82, accepted):

*Updated August, 2012*:

I did some profiling with these implementations:

```js
/* Test 1: */ b = Math.abs(a);
/* Test 2: */ b = abs(a); //local copy: abs = Math.abs;
/* Test 3: */ b = a < 0 ? a * -1 : a;
/* Test 4: */ b = a < 0 ? -a : a;
```

I got the following result on Windows 7. Values are normalized after the fastest result per browser to make it easier to compare which method is faster:

```
        1:Math 2:abs 3:*-1  4:-    1.0=   Version
Chrome    1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0    111ms  21.0.1180.75 m
Firefox   1.0   1.0   1.2   1.2    127ms  14.0.1
IE        1.4   1.0   1.1   1.0    185ms  9.0.8112
Opera     1.9   1.6   1.1   1.0    246ms  12.00
Safari    1.6   1.6   1.1   1.0    308ms  5.1.7
```

**Conclusion:**
When I did this test 3 years ago, -a was fastest, but now Math.abs(x) is faster in Firefox! In Chrome `abs(a)` and `-a` got the same time and it was only 3 ms difference to the slowest method when I tested it with 10 000 000 numbers.

**My Recommendation**: Use **Math.abs(a)**. If you are in a tight loop and by profiling has found it to be too slow, you can use a local reference to the abs function:

```js
var abs=Math.abs; //A local reference to the global Math.abs function
for (i=0;i<1234567890;++i) if ( abs( v[i] ) > 10) ++x;
```

Answer (score 32):

I would suggest picking the method that more clearly shows your intention, rather than worrying about the performance.  In this case, the performance gain of multiplying by -1 is probably minimal.

When you use `Math.abs()`, it is very clear that you want a positive value.  When you use `* -1` it is not clear, and requires more investigation to determine if the input value is always negative.

Comment: +1.  The first rule of optimization: *"don't do it"*.  The second rule of optimization (experts only!): *"don't do it...yet."*  :-)

Comment: Initially I wanted to disagree with your by-the-book answer to avoid premature optimizations, as JS **was** missing compiler optimizations due to being **interpreted**. It made sense to use these little tricks to increase performance, if it really mattered. However, modern browsers **do (jit-)compile** JS, making such optimizations more and more obsolete.

Answer (score 11):

I suppose it depends on the implementation, but `Math.abs` could be as simple as:

```
function abs(x) {
    return x < 0 ? x * -1 : x;
}
```

So, in theory, it just adds a quick test before multiplying.

But, yes, negating a negative sign is the sole purpose. The point is that a simple `x * -1` is also counter-productive for positive values.

---

@olliej [comments]

True. Simple edit, though. ;)

```
function abs(x) {
    return Number(x < 0 ? x * -1 : x);
}
```

Comment: That's not *technically* correct as abs is defined as return a number.  If i did abs(true) or abs(false) i should get 0 or 1, whereas your function will produce true or false.

function abs(x) { if (x < 0) return -x; return +x; }

should do, but i'm not 100% it will handle 0/-0 correctly.

Comment: (Random factoid: in current WebKit nightlies that's actually faster than using Math.abs)

Comment: You don't want the call to Number, that requires a resolve to the global object, etc.  Unary + does sufficient work.

Comment: Instead of doing your own abs you can use the browsers built in: var abs = Math.abs; alert( abs(-1) );

Answer (score 5):

Just the `*-1` operation is probably faster, but keep in mind that the end result *differs* from the result for math.abs().

`math.abs(-5)` and `math.abs(5)` both return 5.

`-5 * -1` returns 5 as well.

`5 * -1` returns -5.

So unless you're absolutely sure that the number is negative to begin with, you have to do some tests, which cost more time. Might as well do math.abs().

But really, if the performance difference between abs() and *-1 matters in your JS, your probably have more serious issues.

Answer (score 2):

A style question: Why use `a * -1` instead of `-a`?
Apart from that I agree that you should use `abs()` if you don't know the sign of the number beforehand. I would not care for speed but for readability.