# making a variable value positive

Tags: javascript, math

I have a variable that will sometimes be negative and sometimes positive.

Before I use it I need to make it positive. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 61):

Use the [Math.abs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp) method.

There is a comment below about using negation (thanks Kelly for making me think about that), and it is slightly faster vs the `Math.abs` over a large amount of conversions if you make a local reference to the `Math.abs` function (without the local reference `Math.abs` is much slower).

Look at the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441893/in-javascript-which-is-faster-math-absvalue-or-value-1) for more detail.  Over small numbers the difference is negligible, and I think Math.abs is a much cleaner way of "self documenting" the code.

Comment: Use negation instead. No function call needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701822/making-a-variable-value-positive/1702175#1702175

Comment: I have to agree with @Kevin here. while "a = -a;" is explicit, it still triggers math phobia in some people which includes developers. Math.abs() seems to say the same thing but uses a different part of the brain. I wouldn't comment Math.abs() but i might for "a = -a".

Comment: This is old, but I would like to point out the reason you would use abs over just negating the variabel is if you didn't know if it was positive or negative and didn't want to use an if statement to check.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Not everyone knows the term "absolute value".

Comment: @callum but every programmer should.

Comment: @MarksaysReinstateMonica eventually, sure, but some programmers are just starting out!

Answer (score 28):

Between these two choices (thanks to @Kooilnc for the example):

```
Number.prototype.abs = function(){
    return Math.abs(this);
};
```

and

```
var negative = -23, 
    positive = -negative>0 ? -negative : negative;
```

go with the second (negation).  It doesn't require a function call and the CPU can do it in very few instructions.  Fast, easy, and efficient.

Comment: Math is heavily optimized by the JS engine, I don't think it will be slower than the second option.

Comment: I wonder how the compiler optimizes the Math.abs() call, anyone care to look and share with us?

Comment: Confirmed that `Math.abs` is almost 10 times faster on Chrome: https://jsperf.com/ternary-vs-math-abs

Comment: @KellyS.French I would think that `Math.abs` simply sets the first bit to a 0 
without any conditionals, since JS numbers are implemented as floating points.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 wouldn't that mess up the 2's complement when the number starts as negative?

Comment: @KellyS.French JS only has floating point numbers. Floating point numbers do not use two's complement. They simply have a flag bit at the MSB.

Answer (score 17):

```
if (myvar < 0) {
  myvar = -myvar;
}
```

or

```
myvar = Math.abs(myvar);
```

Comment: So doing -myvar to a value like -900 makes it negative of -900 or 900?

Comment: A negative negative is positive.  So -(-900) == 900.

Comment: Yes, since two negatives make a positive.  I would use Math.abs() though

Comment: Er, that's math, not programming.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a jQuery implementation but uses the Math library from Javascript

x = Math.abs(x);

Comment: Bravo!  Not every solution needs to use jQuery.  Great library but over used.

Answer (score 2):

or, if you want to avoid function call (and branching), you can use this code:

```
x = (x ^ (x >> 31)) - (x >> 31);
```

it's a bit "hackish" and it looks nice in some odd way :) but I would still stick with `Math.abs` (just wanted to show one more way of doing this)

btw, this works only if underlying javascript engine stores integers as 32bit, which is case in firefox 3.5 on my machine (which is 32bit, so it might not work on 64bit machine, haven't tested...)

Comment: Sure, it is another way. But it is not clear what you do, less readable than Math.abs and if that isn't enough, it is also slower than Math.abs(x) on Firefox 3.6. If you must complicate things, use `x < 0 ? -x : x` (the fastest in the other tested browsers). Your code is 1% slower in Opera 10.63, 12% slower in Chrome 6.0 and 20% slower in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel like using Math.Abs you can you this simple if statement :P

```
if (x < 0) {
    x = -x;
}
```

Of course you could make this a function like this

```
function makePositive(number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        number = -number;
    }
}
```

makepositive(-3) => 3
makepositive (5) => 5

Hope this helps! Math.abs will likely work for you but if it doesn't this little