# how to convert -1 to 1 with javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, integer, negative-number

how to convert -1 to 1 with javascript ?

```
var count = -1; //or any other number -2 -3 -4 -5 ...
```

or

```
var count = 1; //or any other number 2 3 4 5 ...
```

result should be

```
var count = 1; //or any other number 2 3 4 5 ...
```

Comment: here's a question related to this one that is more focused on which of the answers below are faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441893/in-javascript-which-is-faster-math-absvalue-or-value-1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 count = Math.abs(count)
 // will give you the positive value of any negative number
```

Answer (score 3):

The abs function turns all numbers positive: i.e Math.abs( -1 ) = 1

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach (might be faster then `Math.abs`, untested):

```
count = -5;
alert((count ^ (count >> 31)) - (count >> 31));
```

Note that bitwise operations in javascript are always in 32-bit.

Comment: In FF3.6 your code is 6% slower than Math.abs (the fastest method in FF3.6), and compared to `v < 0 ? -v : v` (the fastest in the other tested browsers) your code is 1% slower in Opera 3.6, 12% slower in Chrome 6.0 and 20% slower in IE8.

Comment: In the comment above I meant Opera 10.63.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of interest is `input`... In addition to **[`Math.abs(input)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)**....

```
var count = (input < 0 ? -input : input);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LMw7K/)**

(*edit: as Some pointed out `-input` is faster than `-1 * input`*)

The above makes use of the **[Javascript conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator)**. This is the only ternary (taking three operands) Javascript operator.

The syntax is:

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

If the `condition` is true, `expr1` is evaluated, if it's fales `expr2` is evaluated.

Comment: If not using Math.abs (the cleanest way to show what you want to do, and also the fastest in FF3.6) try `v < 0 ? v * -1 : v` instead, it's faster than *-1.

Comment: @some - How is what I have... `input < 0 ? input * -1 : input` different from ------------------------ `v < 0 ? v * -1 : v` ?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `v < 0 ? -v : v`. That's the fastest one in Opera 10.63, Chrome 6.3 and IE8. `Math.abs(v)` is fastest in Firefox 3.6.

Comment: You want to know how much slower? About 1,4% in opera 10.63, about 2% in FF3.6, about 1% in IE8. In Chrome 6.3 the difference is too small to measure.